# Javascript code to coloring drawings. How does it work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand, how does the code that make the page bellow to work:
http://www.coloring.com/online/eagle-head-flag

All that I know is that the image loaded is a png 32 bits file.
I tried to understand the code in the file **coloring.js** that is loaded on the page. But I coundn't. It looks so simple to be doing that.

The harder think for me to understand, is why, when the user color one of the flag's stars for example, all of them get the same color.

I analyzed the image on fireworks, and it has no layers. So a really can not understand how it is done.

I also could not find any simple example on google, about how to do that.

Can someone help me, at least, where can I find a simple sample asbout this.

Comment: It won't let you implement that exact functionality, as it will fill only the area clicked on (one stripe of the flag, not all of them), but there is an article with detailed explanations on how to implement a paint bucket functionality in javascript at: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/. You can however run a postcheck if, after the bucket has been applied on the image, a given pixel has been colored, then color in the other stripes as well.

Comment: Somehow, the problem could be rephrased as a special type of chloropleth map: http://bl.ocks.org/4060606

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple on the page, because the server handles the "coloring" of each region.

When you click the image it sends an image request for this URL:
http://image.coloring.com/pictures/single/eagle-head-flag?color=F69679&x=449&y=263

[image]

Where `color` is your current color, and `x` and `y` are the coordinates you clicked.

The server returns an image that has the element you clicked on in the color you had selected.  It then puts that image under the outline image.  These are partly transparent so they can be stacked.  You keep clicking and it keeps stacking.

Not sure how they do it server side in order to know what element you click and how they are generating the images.

> The harder think for me to understand, is why, when the user color one
>   of the flag's stars for example, all of them get the same color.

This is because the server thinks of those stars as a single element or region.  Again how it decides that, there is no way to know without their server code.

Lastly when you click done, it just generates a big URL with all the regions colored encoded in it, which the server can generate an image with that fills everything in:
http://image.coloring.com/pictures/colored/aXSH3sI2wz9J/IaebaOnG5C/83b6Ulg2/8CwNyM5M/aKSc4Coh/Ojzg1BeO/CWW2uEJ6ao/zcTvWnSc/DXCbJuVU/N5ZrH71ZbuvwmhrH/D3szJmBY/85T0rLZo/1540n/eagle-head-flag.gif

Answer (score 1):

It's all done server-side.  When the image is clicked, the selected color and the x and y coordinates are sent to the server, which streams back an image, which is displayed on the page.  Here is the relevant code, modified slightly for readability:

```
$('#overlay').click(function(e) {
    x = e.pageX - parseInt($(this).offset().left);
    y = e.pageY - parseInt($(this).offset().top);
    var region = new Image();
    var src = imageUrl + '/pictures/single/' + pictureKeyName +'?color='+color+'&x='+x+'&y='+y;
    $(region).attr('src', src).load(function() {
        $(this).addClass('single');
        $(this).hide().insertBefore('#overlay');
        $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get this done with SVG.

Given some SVG:

```
<div id="main">
  <svg id="octocat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="-60 0 420 330" style="fill:#fff;stroke: #000; stroke-opacity: 0.1">
    <path id="puddle" d="m296.94 295.43c0 20.533-47.56 37.176-106.22 37.176-58.67 0-106.23-16.643-106.23-37.176s47.558-37.18 106.23-37.18c58.66 0 106.22 16.65 106.22 37.18z"/>
    <path class="shadow-legs" d="m161.85 331.22v-26.5c0-3.422-.619-6.284-1.653-8.701 6.853 5.322 7.316 18.695 7.316 18.695v17.004c6.166.481 12.534.773 19.053.861l-.172-16.92c-.944-23.13-20.769-25.961-20.769-25.961-7.245-1.645-7.137 1.991-6.409 4.34-7.108-12.122-26.158-10.556-26.158-10.556-6.611 2.357-.475 6.607-.475 6.607 10.387 3.775 11.33 15.105 11.33 15.105v23.622c5.72.98 11.71 1.79 17.94 2.4z"/>
    <path class="shadow-legs" d="m245.4 283.48s-19.053-1.566-26.16 10.559c.728-2.35.839-5.989-6.408-4.343 0 0-19.824 2.832-20.768 25.961l-.174 16.946c6.509-.025 12.876-.254 19.054-.671v-17.219s.465-13.373 7.316-18.695c-1.034 2.417-1.653 5.278-1.653 8.701v26.775c6.214-.544 12.211-1.279 17.937-2.188v-24.113s.944-11.33 11.33-15.105c0-.01 6.13-4.26-.48-6.62z"/>
    <path id="cat" d="m378.18 141.32l.28-1.389c-31.162-6.231-63.141-6.294-82.487-5.49 3.178-11.451 4.134-24.627 4.134-39.32 0-21.073-7.917-37.931-20.77-50.759 2.246-7.25 5.246-23.351-2.996-43.963 0 0-14.541-4.617-47.431 17.396-12.884-3.22-26.596-4.81-40.328-4.81-15.109 0-30.376 1.924-44.615 5.83-33.94-23.154-48.923-18.411-48.923-18.411-9.78 24.457-3.733 42.566-1.896 47.063-11.495 12.406-18.513 28.243-18.513 47.659 0 14.658 1.669 27.808 5.745 39.237-19.511-.71-50.323-.437-80.373 5.572l.276 1.389c30.231-6.046 61.237-6.256 80.629-5.522.898 2.366 1.899 4.661 3.021 6.879-19.177.618-51.922 3.062-83.303 11.915l.387 1.36c31.629-8.918 64.658-11.301 83.649-11.882 11.458 21.358 34.048 35.152 74.236 39.484-5.704 3.833-11.523 10.349-13.881 21.374-7.773 3.718-32.379 12.793-47.142-12.599 0 0-8.264-15.109-24.082-16.292 0 0-15.344-.235-1.059 9.562 0 0 10.267 4.838 17.351 23.019 0 0 9.241 31.01 53.835 21.061v32.032s-.943 11.33-11.33 15.105c0 0-6.137 4.249.475 6.606 0 0 28.792 2.361 28.792-21.238v-34.929s-1.142-13.852 5.663-18.667v57.371s-.47 13.688-7.551 18.881c0 0-4.723 8.494 5.663 6.137 0 0 19.824-2.832 20.769-25.961l.449-58.06h4.765l.453 58.06c.943 23.129 20.768 25.961 20.768 25.961 10.383 2.357 5.663-6.137 5.663-6.137-7.08-5.193-7.551-18.881-7.551-18.881v-56.876c6.801 5.296 5.663 18.171 5.663 18.171v34.929c0 23.6 28.793 21.238 28.793 21.238 6.606-2.357.474-6.606.474-6.606-10.386-3.775-11.33-15.105-11.33-15.105v-45.786c0-17.854-7.518-27.309-14.87-32.3 42.859-4.25 63.426-18.089 72.903-39.591 18.773.516 52.557 2.803 84.873 11.919l.384-1.36c-32.131-9.063-65.692-11.408-84.655-11.96.898-2.172 1.682-4.431 2.378-6.755 19.25-.80 51.38-.79 82.66 5.46z"/>
    <path id="face" d="m258.19 94.132c9.231 8.363 14.631 18.462 14.631 29.343 0 50.804-37.872 52.181-84.585 52.181-46.721 0-84.589-7.035-84.589-52.181 0-10.809 5.324-20.845 14.441-29.174 15.208-13.881 40.946-6.531 70.147-6.531 29.07-.004 54.72-7.429 69.95 6.357z"/>
    <path id="eyes" d="m160.1 126.06 c0 13.994-7.88 25.336-17.6 25.336-9.72 0-17.6-11.342-17.6-25.336 0-13.992 7.88-25.33 17.6-25.33 9.72.01 17.6 11.34 17.6 25.33z m94.43 0 c0 13.994-7.88 25.336-17.6 25.336-9.72 0-17.6-11.342-17.6-25.336 0-13.992 7.88-25.33 17.6-25.33 9.72.01 17.6 11.34 17.6 25.33z"/>
    <path id="pupils" d="m154.46 126.38 c0 9.328-5.26 16.887-11.734 16.887s-11.733-7.559-11.733-16.887c0-9.331 5.255-16.894 11.733-16.894 6.47 0 11.73 7.56 11.73 16.89z m94.42 0 c0 9.328-5.26 16.887-11.734 16.887s-11.733-7.559-11.733-16.887c0-9.331 5.255-16.894 11.733-16.894 6.47 0 11.73 7.56 11.73 16.89z"/>
    <circle id="nose" cx="188.5" cy="148.56" r="4.401"/>
    <path id="mouth" d="m178.23 159.69c-.26-.738.128-1.545.861-1.805.737-.26 1.546.128 1.805.861 1.134 3.198 4.167 5.346 7.551 5.346s6.417-2.147 7.551-5.346c.26-.738 1.067-1.121 1.805-.861s1.121 1.067.862 1.805c-1.529 4.324-5.639 7.229-10.218 7.229s-8.68-2.89-10.21-7.22z"/>
    <path id="octo" d="m80.641 179.82 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m8.5 4.72 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m5.193 6.14 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m4.72 7.08 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m5.188 6.61 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m7.09 5.66 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m9.91 3.78 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m9.87 0 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z m10.01 -1.64 c0 1.174-1.376 2.122-3.07 2.122-1.693 0-3.07-.948-3.07-2.122 0-1.175 1.377-2.127 3.07-2.127 1.694 0 3.07.95 3.07 2.13z"/>
    <path id="drop" d="m69.369 186.12l-3.066 10.683s-.8 3.861 2.84 4.546c3.8-.074 3.486-3.627 3.223-4.781z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can listen for a click event. This will give you a reference to the SVG path that was clicked on and you can use that reference to set the fill color programmatically.

Using jQuery, for instance, you could do:

```
var _currentFill = "style:#f00"; // red
$("#octocat").click(function (event) { $(event.target).attr('style', _currentFill); })
```

Then all you have to do is change the value of _colorFill whenever the user selects a new color swatch.

I provided an interactive demo as a Gist: http://bl.ocks.org/4545199. Tested on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.